# Using Customer SessionFactory in ViewModel

Tags: magento2, customer-session, viewmodel

I am trying to retrieve customer data from the Customer session in `ViewModel`.

`app/code/Magento/Module/ViewModel/Template.php`

Due to FPC enabled, the session value is not retrieved. However, when I use `Magento\Customer\Model\SessionFactory` the values are updated and retrieved properly.

Below is the code snipped of sessionFactory

```
use Magento\Customer\Model\SessionFactory;

public function getCustomerId(): ?string
{
    $sessionObj = $this->customerSession->create();
    if($sessionObj->isLoggedIn())
    {
        return $sessionObj->getCustomerId();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Is it the correct way to retrieve Session data using SessionFactory? Also, is there any alternative better way to do so?

Comment: I think its better way. I tried to search for interface for it but was unable to  find , so as of now for me its better and within the magento standard practicse.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problem with posted code. However, if you only need **customer_id**, this is an alternative which works fine with FPC

```
public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context $httpContext,
    ...
) {
    $this->_httpContext = $httpContext;
    ...
}

public function getCustomerId()
{
    return $this->_httpContext->getValue('customer_id');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using SessionFactory is a good way for checking customer is logged in in cached page.

Or you can chose another way by using
`Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context` class.

Example

`$this->context->getValue(\Magento\Customer\Model\Context::CONTEXT_AUTH)`

Hope it help!